# that something is semantically correct means it’s correct in a matter of fact?

Tags: philosophy-of-language, semantics

that language is semantically correct means it’s correct in a matter of fact? That is, it has accordance with fact?

Comment: Please add context on where the question comes from and explain the terminology in it. Is "language" a sentence, an argument, a theory? Is "semantically correct" supposed to be "true", "sound", "semantically valid"?

Comment: @Conifold sentence, true, semantically vaild

Comment: Add it to the post and fix the grammar.

Comment: @Conifold :)  :)  :)

Comment: If a sentence is semantically satisfied, then its terms correspond factwise to objects that satisfy it, so I would guess that there could be a correlation between semantic satisfaction and accordance with fact? Is that what you mean, alice?

Comment: "My cat won the Palme d'Or at the last Cannes film festival" is semantically correct, yet I can assure you it is not in accordance with facts.

Comment: @Kristian Berry Yes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most common settings, "a sentence is semantically correct" means the sentence meaning/thesis is consistent with what its author really what to explicitly say or implicitly express. For example usually people have typos or serious syntactic errors in their sentence, but we sometimes still can fully understand its meaning, and as long as its reflected meaning is very close to what the author's exact meaning, we can say the sentence is semantically correct. So strictly speaking, it may not exactly means "correct in matter of fact". However, usually we do require "correct in matter of fact" in such a claim of "semantically correct". Maybe you can provide more background as to why you have such a question in your mind?

Comment: Because people in englishstackexchange say to go, because the questions I made are related to a matter of fact.

Comment: But I made questions about semantics...